# Automated outgoing money transfer for payouts?

Tags: api, transfer, money

At the end of a month I'll need to automatically transfer money from an account to a huge number of other accounts. This has to happen automatically through an API because the amounts for the transactions are all different and come from a database.

I need to find a solution or provider for this. Any suggestions? I'm from Germany so a German or at least European provider would be great.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has mass pay, but requires recipients have a PayPal account (plus, it's PayPal, caveat emptor).

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside

Find a payment provider with ACH capabilities and an API -- that would allow you to write your own implementation (e.g. pay this account $x, pay that account $Y). But fees can get ridiculous if the transfers cross borders.

As you’re looking for a German or European provider, I'll let someone else answer which specific ones to look into (I'm in the US).

2 seemingly global options:

http://www.payoneer.com/articles/masspay.aspx

https://www.alertpay.com/en/masspay.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your payees are in the US you can use ACH direct deposit through a service such as http://www.achdirect.com/

For people who can't get ACH deposits your fallback would probably have to be PayPal which is pretty common.